PHP SQLSRV STORED PROC - Hanging Browser
I have a stored procedure that I would like to run from a simple button click.
The stored procedure takes 5-10 mins to run direct from SMSS.
I'm not looking to return any results to the browser, so I would prefer if the browser didn't hang whilst the stored procedure was running.
I'm using the following to trigger the SP on button click.
$sp_exec = "EXEC [sp_name]";
$sp_exec_qry = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sp_exec];

Is there a way to stop php waiting for the script to finish?
to background it somehow?
Apologies if this is very amateur, just learning as I go :)
Thanks

Seems like you need an asynchronous process

Have you considered executing the stored procedure from a SQL Agent job step and just having your PHP page start the job?

Implement a javascript function so button just posts somewhere and use callbacks from that to handle the results.

@AlwaysLearning Worked a treat! Thank you so much!

The only problem is that you don't know when the job is finished since it's ran async

@siggemannen i've added flags to the table that my page checks for.
